# checking for a character on the end of a string

Tags: c++

Im trying to check for underscore on the end of a string, I have this code but Im still not sucessfull with it. It is checking only for the underscore on the beginning of the string.
as I commented, condition checking last character is not here...I dont know how to code it in..

```
void Convert(string input){
string output = "";
string flag = "";
bool underscore = false;
bool uppercase = false;
if ( islower(input[0]) == false){
    cout << "Error!" <<endl;
    return;
}

for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++){
    if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || (input[i]) == '_') == false){
        cout << "Error!" <<endl;
        return;
    }
    if (islower(input[i])){
        if (underscore){
            underscore = false;
            output += toupper(input[i]);
        }
        else
            output += input[i];

    }
    else if (isupper(input[i])){
        if (flag == "C" || uppercase){
            cout << "Error!"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        flag = "Java";
        output += '_';
        output += tolower(input[i]);

    }
    else if (input[i] == '_'){
        if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
        cout << "Error!" <<endl;
        return;
        }
        flag = "C";
        underscore = true;
    }

}
cout << output <<endl

;
```

}

edit /looking for underscore on the end of string/>

```
for (int i=input.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
         if ( input[i]=='_' ){
         cout<<"Chyba"<<endl;
         break;
         } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks kinda weird, and that might be making it difficult to understand. Let's rearrange it and remove some brackets:

```
if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || (input[i]) == '_') == false){
if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || input[i] == '_'  ) == false){
if ( !(isalpha(input[i])  || input[i] == '_') ){
if (! ( isalpha(input[i]) || input[i] == '_' ) ){
```

Note that the `!` means `not`, which makes a false statement true. This does the same thing as your `==false`, but in an (arguably clearer way).

So it looks like what you're saying is:

```
If this character is an Alpha or an Underscore, don't continue.
```

But what you are trying to ask is:

```
Is there an underscore at the end of the string?
```

Since you're interested in the end of the string, why not reverse your for-loop?

```
for (int i=input.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
```

Note that since arrays in C++ are [0-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), the length of the string is 1 greater than its end, so we start at the `input.size()-1` character.

Then why don't we ignore blank spaces and stop if we see an underscore?

```
for (int i=input.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
  if( input[i]==' ' || input[i]=='\t' )
    continue;
  else if ( isalpha(input[i]) ){
    cout<<"String ends with an alpha."<<endl;
    break;
  } else if ( input[i]=='_' ){
    cout<<"String ends with an underscore."<<endl;
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that the use of `else if` and `continue` and `break` makes it very easy to follow what's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is check whether the last element of the string is an underscore, then

```
if (!input.empty())
  return *(input.rbegin()) == '_';
```

or

```
if (!input.empty())
  return input[input.size()-1] == '_';
```

Comment: Don't you mean `rbegin` in your first example?

Comment: well, it not just to check whether the last one is underscore, check my code now, I want to check more positions, all of them are working but I dont think there is a condition which checks last character of a string..

Comment: @feri You wrote "Im trying to check for underscore on the end of a string..." and your question title is "checking for a character on the end of a string". If you want to ask a different question, then ask a different question.

Comment: @juanchopanza, sorry I mean underscore, I didnt mean to check for a different character...its all about the one underscore at the last place in a string..

Comment: @feri exactly, and I told you how to find an underscore at the end of the string.

Comment: Im just learning how to programm and its kind of difficult to include this function into my whole code..

Answer (score 2):

Or in C++11 use back

```
if (!input.empty())
  return input.back() == '_';
```